# Clickhouse - TTL - Move data to another table

Tags: clickhouse, materialized-views, ttl

Is it possible to transfer expired data into another table ? I want to implement an efficient mechanism to transfer previous day data into weekly table, previous week data into monthly table etc.

I don't want to use multiple materialized views, to not calculate summary data for each table when new data comes.

Any design suggestion to handle this is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

- TTL Group by : https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/14345
- GraphiteMergeTree: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/graphitemergetree/
- clear column: https://github.com/kshvakov/ClickHouse-CPP-Meetup#summingmergetree